# angular translate instant method does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a website with angular translate. It works perfectly. We have a variable that we want to fixate with a certain language key. Let's say the site's language has 'en' and 'zh' as options, I want a certain translation to return with 'zh' no matter the language choice.

By browsing the [API reference](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.%24translate), I found a method called Instant to do just that. However, it doesn't work when we try to call

```
$translate.instant('zh', 'TRANSLATION_ID')
```

It returns an error of

```
TypeError: Object function (a,b,e){var f=d?n[d]:n,i=e?w[e]:u;if(f&&f.hasOwnProperty(a))return i.interpolate(f[a],b);if(h&&!v&&g.get(h)(a,d),d&&c&&d!==c){var j=n[c][a];if(j){var k;return i.setLocale(c),k=i.interpolate(j,b),i.setLocale(d),k}}return l&&(a=[l,a...<omitted>...a} has no method 'instant'
```

I wonder how to use the isntant method correctly.

Comment: Can you point to the docs for the function also when debugging you should use non-minified source when available otherwise the errors dont' tell you much.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like you don't use the method correctly, or probably just misunderstood it.

`$translate.instant('ID')` expects the translation id as **first** parameter and interpolation params as **second** parameter. It then translate the id **synchronously** instead of **asynchronously** (which is what `$translate()` does).

What you want is explicitly translating a translation id in a certain locale no matter what language key is currently used. This is currently **not** supported **yet**.

Hope that makes things clear.

Comment: I wish the difference between `$translate` and `$translate.instant` was better covered in the documentation. I ran into `infdig` problem when calling `$translate` in scope function, even if the resulting promise was not returned. Anyway, FWIW, the link to instant documentation: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/master/test/unit/service/translate.spec.js#L1605

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you just embed the word in `'zh'`. Don't use `$translate` there since you obviously don't want to translate that word.

If there's another reason for this; I would suggest:

```
// store the current language
var currentLanguage = $translate.use();
// change the language
$translate.use("zh").then(function (translation) {
    // then translate here
    $log.debug($translate.instant('SOME_WORD'));
    // set the previous language back when you're fulfilled
    $translate.use(currentLanguage);
});
```

But since this is async, this may translate some other words to `'zh'` in the meantime.

A third way to achieve this would be setting the **same** translation value for `SOME_WORD` in each language file.

And a forth way I could think of is translating `SOME_WORD` only in the `'en'` file (no translation value in the `'zh'` file) and using `'en'` as the fallback language. Such as: `$translate.fallbackLanguage('en')`

Comment: Because we want to do SEO in zh for some dynamic pages, but Google only crawl us in en.

Comment: So, none of my suggestions is a solution for you?

Comment: @Onur
In my case I have lot of key words which  are getting from JSON file.
When I use $translate.instant, on first load it not able to evaluate.
Can you please help me with this.