# $translate working partially : Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, translate, angular-translate

```
angular
       .module('common.lang', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
       .config(['$translateProvider', langConfig])
       .service('langService', langService);

    function langConfig($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: 'languages/',
            suffix: '.json'
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-GB');
    }
```

I observe that when I use translate on **HTML** side `{{"Title.value"|translate}}`, it works perfectly when I changes the language.

but when I am using it on **angularjs code** side, it only works for english language but for other languages it does not change, it sticks to english only, below is the code

**Html**

```
{{title}}
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.title=$translate.instant('Title.value');
```

Even I saw one blog also

[translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803577/angular-translate-instant-method-does-not-work)

but not able to resolve my issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code changing the language and translating the key. You probable translate before the language change is done

Comment: $translate.use(locale); this is the code on language change in language service where locale is key value

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your controller:

```
$translate.use(language).then(function (translation) {
// translate here
$scope.title=$translate.instant('Title.value');
```

});